# How to fit a model with and without an interaction in a JAGS regression model

Tags: r, bayesian, jags, r2jags

I'm using [this tutorial](http://biometry.github.io/APES//LectureNotes/StatsCafe/Linear_models_jags.html) to wrap my head around JAGS code. In the section **'Same model with an additional categorical predictor'** it states that "This model includes an interaction between sex and body length". How can I remove this so that there's no interaction?

Here's the full setup and model in R and JAGS.

First the data:

```
set.seed(42)

samplesize <- 50 # Larger sample size because we're fitting a more complex model
b_length <- sort(rnorm(samplesize)) # Body length
sex <- sample(c(0, 1), size = samplesize, replace = T) # Sex (0: female, 1: male)

int_true_f <- 30 # Intercept of females
int_true_m_diff <- 5 # Difference between intercepts of males and females
slope_true_f <- 10 # Slope of females
slope_true_m_diff <- -3 # Difference between slopes of males and females

mu <- int_true_f + sex * int_true_m_diff + (slope_true_f + sex * slope_true_m_diff) * b_length # True means
sigma <- 5 # True standard deviation of normal distributions

b_mass <- rnorm(samplesize, mean = mu, sd = sigma) # Body mass (response variable)

# Combine into a data frame:
snakes2 <- data.frame(b_length = b_length, b_mass = b_mass, sex = sex)
head(snakes2)

jagsdata_s2 <- with(snakes2, list(b_mass = b_mass, b_length = b_length, sex = sex, N = length(b_mass)))
```

JAGS code:

```
lm2_jags <- function(){
    # Likelihood:
    for (i in 1:N){
        b_mass[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau) # tau is precision (1 / variance)
        mu[i] <- alpha[1] + sex[i] * alpha[2] + (beta[1] + beta[2] * sex[i]) * b_length[i]
    }
    # Priors:
    for (i in 1:2){
        alpha[i] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
        beta[i] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
    }
    sigma ~ dunif(0, 100)
    tau <- 1 / (sigma * sigma)
}
```

Initial values and run:

```
init_values <- function(){
    list(alpha = rnorm(2), beta = rnorm(2), sigma = runif(1))
}

params <- c("alpha", "beta", "sigma")

fit_lm2 <- jags(data = jagsdata_s2, inits = init_values, parameters.to.save = params, model.file = lm2_jags,
               n.chains = 3, n.iter = 12000, n.burnin = 2000, n.thin = 10, DIC = F)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interaction term is contained in your calculation of mu. The sex changes how the formula between body length and body mass is defined, via the slope terms. To build a model where sex and body length are treated as independent with respect to how they affect body mass, you could do something like this:

```
mu <- int_true_f + (sex * int_true_m_diff) + b_length
```

The JAGS code would then become

```
lm2_jags <- function(){
  # Likelihood:
  for (i in 1:N){
    b_mass[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau) # tau is precision (1 / variance)
    mu[i] <- alpha[1] + (sex[i] * alpha[2]) + (b_length[i] * alpha[3])
  }
  # Priors:
  for (i in 1:3){
    alpha[i] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
  }
  sigma ~ dunif(0, 100)
  tau <- 1 / (sigma * sigma)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, to clarify why are there 3 alpha values if we're calculating two intercepts? Or is that for the 2 intercepts and 1 common slope?

Comment: The latter, to my understanding. It is for he two coefficients and the common one.